# How to retrieve zip file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, zip

I have following code in my Asp Web Api Controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage Download(RequestModel model)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            string dataPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            AttachmentsHelper attachmentsHelper = new AttachmentsHelper(model, dataPath);
            string attachmentsFile = attachmentsHelper.GetAttachments();

            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(attachmentsFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "photos";
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
            return response;
        }
```

When I request this method via Ajax I get Result that looks weird in my FireBug
[image: Result from web api in FireBug]

How can I force my browser to start download returned file?

Comment: How are you retrieving it via JavaScript?

Comment: All I do for now is to use console.log with response. I use Angular's $http service. Response is argument of $http success callback. I don't know how to start with it.

Comment: Well, it's not weird then. It's like trying to open a picture with notepad. To make your browser download the file you need to set the `document.location = address_of_the_method_the_returns_the_file`.

Comment: Thank you a lot  @Nasreddine. Suddenly it became clear to me!